# Как вывести html внутри #pasp_option?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

```
<select id="pasp_option"></select>
```

-

```
function generate_pasport() {
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport", {}, function (data) {
        $("#pasp_option").html(data);
    });
}

generate_pasport();
alert($("#pasp_option").html());
```

Comment: Причина в том что alert выполняется первым хоть на последнем месте стоит а запросы $("#pasp_option").load("http://test/admin/generate_pasport");
после  ааа=$("#pasp_option").html(); alert(ааа);
когда нажимаешь "ОК"

как сделать чтобы первым отправлялся запрос?

Comment: Поставить алерт следующей строкой после `$("#pasp_option").html(data);`

Answer (score 1):

Если принять за факт, что страница `<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport` отдает вам результат в виде

```
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
...
```

то ошибки быть не должно.

---

Конечно же тут нужны теги js:

```
<script>
</script>
```

+в вашем случае наиболее подходит оператор `.load()`.
Итого, на выходе получим код:

```
<select id="pasp_option"></select> 
<script>
    $("#pasp_option").load("<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport");
</script>
```

Comment: Да это так!

Comment: дополнил ответ

Comment: alert($("#pasp_option").html()); не работает это?

Comment: все должно работать. 99% ошибка в файле generate_pasport.
Перейдите по этой ссылке в браузере `<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport` - вы видите то, что должна вывести страница?

Comment: Это не работает, отсюда выводится  это `<option value='3'>111</option><option value='6'>114</option>`

    $("#pasp_option").load("<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport");

Это работает

    $("#pasp_option").html("<option value='3'>111</option><option value='6'>114</option>");

    ааа=$("#pasp_option").html(); 
    alert(ааа);

Comment: `<?php echo base_url();?>` уберите этот кусок кода, сделайте путь относительным. в качестве теста добавьте `<div id='log'></div>` и загрузите в него ответ `$("#log").load("admin/generate_pasport");`

Comment: `$("#pasp_option").load("<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport");`

Если написать вот так, то все работает

    $("#gruppa").click(function() {
        ааа=$("#pasp_option").html();
        alert(ааа);
    });

почему не выводится это

    $("#pasp_option").load("<?php echo base_url();?>admin/generate_pasport");

    ааа=$("#pasp_option").html();
    alert(ааа);

Comment: причины 2: либо путь к файлу неправильный, либо файл возвращает некорректный результат. со скриптами все нормально.